# How do I block certain routes when not in Debug Mode in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, security, debugging, routes

Is there a way to make a route `APP_DEBUG` exclusive in Laravel 8?

I can set routes in the `PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance` middleware exception list.
But that is only for when maintenance mode is on.

I know I can simply do an abort(403) on a Route if Debug mode is on but I'm using [Laravel Web Console](https://github.com/alkhachatryan/laravel-web-console) library which communicates with it's own route when executing commands. So I need to strictly block any requests to that route when in Debug mode.

I want to block certain routes when not in Debug mode. Does Laravel come with such option or do I need a third party library?

Comment: This seems like a use case for Middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James suggested it, I tinkered with middlewares and registered a global middleware to abort 403 if any uri matches one from a blacklist.

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    // allows blocking some requests when debug mode is off
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringProduction::class,
];
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class PreventRequestsDuringProduction
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $blacklist = [
            'console',
            'laravelwebconsole/execute'
        ];
        $uri = Route::getRoutes()->match($request)->uri;
        
        if(\in_array($uri, $blacklist) && !env('APP_DEBUG')) {
            abort(403);
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also ` Laravel Web Console` provides a custom login is a small addition to the protection.
So you will able to set strong password protection as well.

Comment: Yes, that helps too. But I discovered that  'laravelwebconsole/execute' route was exposed and wanted to block it altogether when unneeded.